# ListBox цвет фокуса

Tags: c#, winforms

Как изменить цвет фона выделения и цвет текста в ListBox'e?

Пробовал через *DrawMode*, но там цвет текста изменяет везде, а мне нужно поменять только у фокуса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого нужно :

- переопределить событие [`Drawitem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx)
- установить свойству [`DrawMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode.aspx) значение `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`

Пример обработчика события `Drawitem` :

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index<0) return;

    // задаем параметры для рисования текущего элемента
    // Если элемент имеет состояние 'выбран' мы изменяем цвет его кисти бэкграунда на желтую, 
    //остальные параемтры оставим по умолчанию взятые из параметра `e`
    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics, 
                                  e.Font, 
                                  e.Bounds, 
                                  e.Index,
                                  e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                  e.ForeColor, 
                                  Color.Yellow);// <- обратить внимание сюда

    // Начинаем рисовать
    // Рисуем Background для каждого элемента
    e.DrawBackground();

    // Рисуем текст для каждого элемента
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(),e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

    // если у текущеного элемента есть фокус, эта функция нарисует фокус
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Вот еще один пример из документации https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: А где тут изменить цвет текста в фокусе?

Comment: @PavelBlokhin, ну я Вам всего лишь примеры привел, как рисовать, а дальше вы логику стройте сами. Проверяйте что элемент в состоянии DrawItemState.Focus и рисуйте текст нужным цветом. Так же и для фона.